# Using Putty to proxy through reverse SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, putty

I have a remote machine *remotePi* which uses autossh to maintain a reverse tunnel to a local machine *localPi*.  When SSH'd into *localPi*, I can reliably ssh into the *remotePi* using localhost:3333.

Now I have a desktop Windows machine *localWin* with a browser which I would like to proxy through to the LAN of *remotePi* to access local HTTP resources.

So far, using Putty, I have been unable to achieve this.  I understand how to do this with a single hop, but the second hop eluding me.  Is this possible directly from Putty, or is there some additional ssh command I need to issue manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Putty Tunnels configuration for the localPi:3333, pick tunnel type **Dynamic** (instead of Local or Remote). Enter source port 3334, leave empty tunnel destination. The final string should read D3334.

Now configure your Windows browser to use SOCKS proxy at localhost:3334.

SOCKS protocol means that even if a Windows browser will send TCP traffic to one IP, the browser includes "inside" the TCP traffic the target IP address. The Dynamic tunnel is SOCKS-compatible, so the tunnel decodes the target IP and instructs your remotePi to connect to target IP on your behalf.

Your communication with localPi:3333 doesn't talk at all to localPi's sshd. It only does 3333 tunneling. The 3334 tunneling is between localWin's putty and remotePi's sshd.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer.  I had already come very close, but your answer spurred me to find the final piece of the puzzle: adding `GatewayPorts yes` to _/etc/ssh/sshd_config_.